# Класс для работы с сетью Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

Есть вот такой код

```
let urlString = "https://someurl.com/api"
let url = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

// Что то делаем с data 

}).resume()
```

Подскажите, как мне всю работу с сетью вынести в отдельный класс а в контроллере только вставлять обращения к методам этого класса? 
Т. е. передать метод, который нужно вызвать и передать результат запроса по завершению.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать библиотеку, одна из самых популярных это [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

А так-же можно реализовать ваши методы через класс

```
final class ApiManager {

    typealias ComplitionHandler = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()

    static func loadDataWithURLString(_ urlString: String, responce: @escaping ComplitionHandler) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: responce).resume()
        } else {
            print("Не получилось преобразовать в URL")
        }
    }
}
```

//Реализация в `UIViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ApiManager.loadDataWithURLString("https://someurl.com/api") { (data, responce, error) in
            // Что то делаем с data
        } 
    }
```